# Parse Header Element of SOAP Enveloper Header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapheader

I am getting the SOAPHeader by using `stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().getMessageContext("In").getEnvelope().getHeader()`
Then i need to parse the value of particullar element inside it, Searched lot but i'm getting null.
i have tried `soapHeader.getAttribute(QName)` `soapHeader.examineAllHeaderBlocks()` etc. and after getting the Iterator i'm not able to get the text of particullar element inside header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 classes, a `HeaderHandler` and a `HeaderHandlerResolver` at that point in your IDE for your client you can right click and click `new webservice client` and point to the wsdl url. Take a look at this http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/

Comment: The tutorial u shared shows to create header element, but here  i already have header element, I just need to get a particular element out of it.

Comment: Oh I see, use an XML parser then, I prefer JAXB because it is standard. See this line `SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();` you can send `message` to the XML parser which should break out the elements for you.